# IMessageMediator doesn't hit breakpoint

Tags: c#, mvvm, catel

I've recently upgraded an old project from Catel 4.3 to Catel 5.0.

The project used the InterestedIn attribute which is no longer supported.
I tried replacing it with the  IMediator but can't get it to work.

In the ViewModel that Listens I have the following code:

```
private IMessageMediator _messageMediator;

public CustomerControlViewModel(IMessageMediator messageMediator)
{
    Argument.IsNotNull(() => messageMediator);
    _messageMediator = messageMediator;
}

[MessageRecipient(Tag = "AddCustomerWindowViewModel")]
protected void AddCustomerWindowViewModelExecuted(string value)
{
    if (value == "OnAccept")
        RetrieveCustomers();
}
```

And in the sending ViewModel I have:

```
public AddCustomerWindowViewModel(IMessageMediator messageMediator)
{
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => messageMediator);
        _messageMediator = messageMediator;
}

private void OnAccept()
{

    _messageMediator.SendMessage("OnAccept","AddCustomerWindowViewModel");

}
```

But when I place a breakpoint on the listener it never hits

I'm missing something, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked the code and unit tests for you.

1. I recommend that you use constants for your tags (to prevent any typos)
2. You should register the recipient as you can see here:

https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/develop/src/Catel.Tests/Messaging/MessageMediatorFacts.cs#L199

From what I remember, the view models in Catel should auto-register itself as recipients, but maybe we removed it for performance reasons (opt-in model). Couldn't find anything in the release notes though.

Anyway, try registering (and don't forget to unregister!) the vm manually (I recommend in InitializeAsync and CloseAsync).

Comment: Between the holidays and an unplanned company merger this project was stalled, but finally found time to work on again. Registering the message made the difference. I've a follow up question; is it better to pass the IMessageMediator by injecting it in the constructor or let the viewmodel find it by using MyServiceLocator.ResolveType<IMessageMediator>();

Comment: complete code for last piece is var MyDependencyResolverManager = DependencyResolverManager.Default;
            var MyDependencyResolver = MyDependencyResolverManager.GetDependencyResolverForType(typeof(AddCustomerWindowViewModel));
            var MyServiceLocator = MyDependencyResolver.GetServiceLocator();
   
            messageMediator = MyServiceLocator.ResolveType<IMessageMediator>();

Comment: Always inject if possible.

Comment: OK, thanx. Does this also apply to the IUIVisualizerService, IMessageService, and IPLeaseWaitSevice. That injecting is preferred over finding it with the DependecnyResolver?

Comment: Yes, same for any service. If you are interested in more advice, check out the support packages that are available via open collective: https://opencollective.com/catel